# referencing functions within a list

Tags: r

I have a list of functions and I'd like to me able to call them without them being independent objects. For example:

```
funcs <- list(foo = function(a, b) a + b,
              ## in a list, how can I call `foo` from `bar`?
              bar = function(m) foo(m, m/2))
```

I'm looking for something akin to moving up and over in a directory from the current location (e.g. `../foo`) but as a function call.

Some context:

There is a package that has some predefined [modeling elements](https://github.com/topepo/caret/tree/master/models/files). There have been some requests for new features that would require to know the range of parameter values. Those are current encoded in functions in a list. For example, for partial least squares, the parameter values can range between 1 and the number of predictors in the data set:

```
modelInfo <- list(## other list elements
    grid = function(x, y, len = NULL, search = "grid") {
        if(search == "grid") {
            out <- data.frame(ncomp = seq(1, min(ncol(x) - 1, len), by = 1))
        } else {
            out <- data.frame(ncomp = unique(sample(1:ncol(x), replace = TRUE)))
        } 
        out
    },
    ## more list elements
)
```

I'd like to add a list element called `bounds` that will encode the possible values and have `grid` references them. I could pass in the `bounds` function data into `grid` but that would add new arguments and break a lot of backwards compatibility. I didn't think that any other solution would be possible to reference `bounds` from `grid` without a significant change in code.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? This question reads like the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Lists in R don't create their own environments and functions in R are executed in the environment in which they were created.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use a list like that. You probably should be using a proper enclosure with proper functions. Your example isn't quite complete or clear enough to test possible solutions. If you made a proper minimal [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) it would be easier to help and test possible solutions. Why does it **have** to be a list?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a list, use an environment:

```
env <- new.env()
env$foo <- function(a, b) a + b
env$bar <- function(m) foo(m, m/2)
environment(env$foo) <- environment(env$bar) <- env

env$bar(3)
# 4.5
```

Comment: The functions already exist in a package and I'm trying to avoid re-writing everything

Comment: ...did you just downvote me for not making use of information you didn't put in your question?

Comment: Sorry if that was rude but the question was about how to solve the problem within that data structure (instead of providing a better structure).

Answer (score 2):

`foo` is not on the search path from `bar`. However, `funcs` is:

```
funcs <- list(foo = function(a, b) a + b,
              bar = function(m) funcs$foo(m, m/2))
funcs$bar(3)
#[1] 4.5
```

If you already have a constructor function, you could do this:

```
constructFuncs <- function() {
  foo <- function(a, b) a + b 
  bar <- function(m) foo(m, m/2)
  list(foo = foo, bar = bar)
}
funcs <- constructFuncs()
funcs$bar(3)  
#[1] 4.5
```

However, I recommend using a better approach. Environments (or possibly even reference classes?) seem preferable to lists in this case.